# How to target an ID with Backstretch

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

I'm using jQuery.Backstretch, I have an animation, but I want to target it to a div with an ID of exp, how to target it? This is what I have:

```
    $.backstretch([
      "img/bg/photo1.jpg",
      "img/bg/photo2.jpg",
      "img/bg/photo3.jpg",
      "img/bg/photo4.jpg"
    ], {
        fade: 950,
        duration: 10000,
    });
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $("#demo").backstretch("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg");
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fcSaF/